# Restart pm2 app every 12h with cron

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

Tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin
* 0,12 * * * pm2 restart all
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are removing the other paths from `$PATH`. Instead, say `PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin`. Also, you need to mention `node`'s path before `pm2` --> `*/5 * * * * /root/.nvm/v0.11.9/bin/node /root/.nvm/v0.11.9/bin/pm2 restart all`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Edit cron with `crontab -e` and add the following:

`0 */12 * * * /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all`

For the schedule, use `0 */12 * * *` for every 12 hours, or `0 0,12 * * *` for 0:00 and 12:00 specifically. (Your schedule, `* 0,12 * * *`, would trigger every minute of hour 0 and hour 12, 0:00, 0:01, 0:02...)

For the command, as fedorqui mentioned, use the path to node followed by the path to pm2 and the pm2 options. Use `which node` and `which pm2` to get the path to node and pm2.

Answer (score 11):

Among multiple restart strategies, PM2 can restart application based on a cron format via the option `--cron-restart`

Restart app every midnight:

```
pm2 start app.js --cron-restart="0 0 * * *"
```

For more information check out the doc:

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/#restart-at-cron-time

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a `process.exit(1)` in the script. :(

Answer (score 4):

Don't restart, [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883269/what-is-the-difference-between-pm2-restart-and-pm2-reload) (zero down-time)

Reload myApp every day at 4:30 AM

```
30 4 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/pm2 reload <myAppId> > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To check the full path of node and pm2 do `which node` and `which pm2`. The portion `> /dev/null 2>&1` ignores the stdout and stderr.